# Tabla de amortización en php

Tags: php

quiero hacer una tabla de amortización donde el usuario dará los datos como:

- Capital
- Interes
- Periodo

La fórmula es multiplicar interés por capital y sumarse al capital las veces que marca el periodo, por ejemplo si capital es 100 interés 0.5 y periodo 10 tendría que ser la operación

100x0.5=50  y ese resultado se suma a capital 50+100=150 y eso se repetiría 10 veces. Se que se podría usar un for pero tengo dudas de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Comparte el código de lo que has hecho, es importante que incluyas lo que tu has hecho y el error que tienes a la hora de ejecutar tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["interes"]))

{

    $_POST["interes"]=str_replace(",",".",$_POST["interes"]);

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tabla Amortización/title>

</head>

 

<style>

form {width:250px;}

form>div>span {width:100px;display: inline-block;text-align:left;}

form input {width:150px;}

form>div {text-align:center;}

</style>

 

<body>

 

<h1>Tabla de Amortización con PHP</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="POST">

    <div>

        <span>Importe :</span>

        <span><input type="text" name="importe" maxlength=9 value="<?php echo $_POST["importe"]?>"></span>

    </div>

    <div>

        <span>Años :</span>

        <span><input type="text" name="anos" maxlength=2 value="<?php echo $_POST["anos"]?>"></span>

    </div>

    <div>

        <span>Interés :</span>

        <span><input type="text" name="interes" maxlength=9 value="<?php echo $_POST["interes"]?>"></span>

    </div>

    <div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Calcular"></p>

    </div>

</form>

 

<?php

if($_POST["importe"] && $_POST["anos"] && $_POST["interes"])

{

    $deuda=$_POST["importe"];

    $anos=$_POST["anos"];

    $interes=$_POST["interes"];

 

    // hacemos los calculos...

    $interes=($interes/100)/12;

    $m=($deuda*$interes*(pow((1+$interes),($anos*12))))/((pow((1+$interes),($anos*12)))-1);

 

    echo "<div>Capital Inicial: ".number_format($deuda,2,",",".")." €";

    echo "<br>Cuota a pagar mensualmente: ".number_format($m,2,",",".")." €</div>";

    ?>

    <table border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>

        <tr>

            <th>Mes</th>

            <th>Intereses</th>

            <th>Amortización</th>

            <th>Capital Pendiente</th>

        </tr>

        <?php

        // mostramos todos los meses...

        for($i=1;$i<=$anos*12;$i++)

        {

            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td align=right>".$i."</td>";

                $totalint=$totalint+($deuda*$interes);

                echo "<td align=right>".number_format($deuda*$interes,2,",",".")."</td>";

                echo "<td align=right>".number_format($m-($deuda*$interes),2,",",".")."</td>";

 

                $deuda=$deuda-($m-($deuda*$interes));

                if ($deuda<0)

                {

                    echo "<td align=right>0</td>";

                }else{

                    echo "<td align=right>".number_format($deuda,2,",",".")."</td>";

                }

            echo "</tr>";

        }

        ?>

    </table>

    Pago total de intereses : <?php echo number_format($totalint,2,",",".")?> €

    <?php

}

?>

 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que quieres algo como esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="form col-md-8 mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">asd</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label for="capital">Capital </label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="capital" id="capital" class="form-control" required>

                <label for="interes">Interes </label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="interes" id="interes" class="form-control" required>

                <label for="periodo">Periodo </label>
                <input type="number" name="periodo" id="periodo" class="form-control" required><br>
                <input type="submit" id="generate" name="generate" value="Generar tabla" class="btn btn-success form-control">
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <?php 
    

    if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
        $capital = $_POST['capital'];
        $interes = $_POST['interes'];
        $periodo = $_POST['periodo'];
        ?>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Periodo</th>
                <th>Capital</th>
                <th>Interes</th>
                
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    
                    while($periodo > $i){
                        $t = $capital*$interes;
                        $capital += $t;
                    echo $t;
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo($i+1); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo($capital); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo($interes); ?></td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $i++;

                    }

                 ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>


        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

No entiendo bien como la quieres, según yo debería llevar más campos, pero esa es la idea, si quieres más ayuda sube un ejemplo de como quedaría la tabla y si puedes ya llena.

Comment: genial muchas gracias con esto arregle mi problema.